# Mouse position and movement inverted on a laptop (19.04)

Tags: amd-graphics, 19.04

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop, which has relatively old AMD GPU (Radeon HD 5650). Now my cursor is completely inverted. 
I did try rotating the screen via xrandr, installing oibaf's drivers, but no result. 
Is there any way possible to fix this on 19.04?

Comment: Can You describe exactly what is going on ? Inverted how ? Horizontally ? Vertically ? Both ?

Comment: Oi, sorry, I forgot about this topic. I moved to arch, however i did manage to fix it by removing "iio-sensor-proxy".

Comment: You may want to consider putting it as an answer to Your own question. As it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, this issue is fixable by removing iio-sensor-proxy